# Add more teapots on an Image Target using Vuforia

Tags: android, image, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm a newbie in Android Vuforia AR development. After google and vuforia forum has no results, I come here and need your suggestions. I successful replace a teapot by my own 3d object, now i need to add another teapots into "stones" target, like this image [link](http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~holl/CS290I/Assignments/Assignments-3/IMG_0097.jpg)? Have you ever work with this case? Please give me some traces to begin.

Thanks and best Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Unity?  Here are two suggestions:

You can programmatically instantiate prefabs on an image target following this code, just add additional transforms:

https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/faq/unity-how-can-i-dynamically-attach-my-3d-model-image-target

Alternatively, in your Scene Hierarchy, you can make additional GameObjects children of the ImageTarget prefab (probably the easiest way), and adjust their position using the Scene Editor.

Comment: Thanks for your response @JAL ! I still did not use Unity. However, can i add new teapots by using Java code? I'm starting to learn Unity, but this software does not support my Laptop's cam.

Comment: @John Sorry for the late reply, but I'm not familiar with the using Vuforia with Java.  Thanks for accepting my answer though.

Answer (score 0):

First, grab a fresh copy of the modelview matrix before transforming it. Second, bind your modelViewProjectionMatrix before using it.

```
modelViewMatrix = QCAR::Tool::convertPose2GLMatrix(trackable->getPose());

SampleUtils::rotatePoseMatrix(5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, &modelViewMatrix.data[0]);
SampleUtils::scalePoseMatrix(kObjectScale, kObjectScale, kObjectScale,
                             &modelViewMatrix.data[0]);
SampleUtils::multiplyMatrix(&projectionMatrix.data[0],
                            &modelViewMatrix.data[0] ,
                            &modelViewProjection.data[0]);

glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpMatrixHandle, 1, GL_FALSE,
                   (GLfloat*)&modelViewProjection.data[0] );

SampleUtils::checkGlError("ImageTargets renderFrame");
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, NUM_TEAPOT_OBJECT_INDEX, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,
               (const GLvoid*) &teapotIndices[0]);
```